# How do i send a function from the server to the client

Tags: node.js, express, server-side, client-side

Im new to post requests in NodeJS & ExpressJS, Im trying to pass in a function (not the function's result) to get called in the client, I have this listener and this post request (Im trying to make a discord bot webview tool)

### The Server-Side

```js
app.post("/dashboardstartup", jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    // authClient is a discord client (Discord Bot)

    if(authClient)
    {
        authClient.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
             // always send the message once its created
             res.json({
                 message
             })
             // the problem is that when I send the result the fetch request from the client stops
        });
    }
})
```

### The Client-Side

```js
// ...

await fetch("http://localhost:8080/dashboardstartup", {
     method: "POST";
     headers: {
         'Content-type': 'application/json'
     }

}).then(a=>a.json()).then(a=>{
   // once the fetch response is received, the fetch stops and the client can't listen to messages anymore

  console.log(a.messsage) // prints out "Hello world!"
})
```

> **And is there any better way to do this, than fetch method?**

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you try to send a function, not the result, but its code to the client and execute this function on the client side (`Im trying to pass in a function (not the function's result) to get called in the client`). If this is right, thats not possible. But i do not see any function to want to send.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the native [`response.write()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#responsewritechunk-encoding-callback) method.

The [`response.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) method comes from the Express.js package and it internally closes the connection after sending the response.

Here's an example of how you can use `.write()`:

```
authClient.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
             // always send the message once its created
             res.write(JSON.stringify({ message }), 'utf8');
        });
```

It doesn't close the connection until you manually do it and the client will keep listening for messages. So remember to end the response when `authClient` ends as well:

```
authClient.on('close', () => res.end());
```

Comment: What about the client-side? should i just use fetch?

Comment: And a discord **BOT** client (authClient) has no event, called "close"